# mixture of gaussian distribution in C++

Tags: c++, probability, gaussian, gsl

I know library like gsl to generate gaussian distributions and generate random number based on gaussian distribution.https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Gaussian-Distribution.html
I am wondering if there are any library which could generate random number obey mixture gaussian distribution and could return the probability of the given value based on mixture gaussian distribution? With many thanks.[image]

**following up** : is it the same if I first generate a random number between (0,1), if it falls into (0, 0.5), I just generate number obey one gaussian distribution, otherwise generate number from the other gaussian distribution. Is this process the same as generating number obey mixture of the two gaussians? (Assuming the weight is equal between the two gaussians)

Comment: Jugging by the graph you posted, I assume by "mixture" you simply mean the sum of two gaussians?

Answer (score 4):

You're correct: You can generate a sample from the Gaussian mixture model in two steps:

- Randomly decide from which Gaussian distribution to sample, depending on the mixture weights.
- Create one random sample from the selected Gaussian distribution.

Here's a minimum working example using the built-in random number generators of C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    using normal_dist   = std::normal_distribution<>;
    using discrete_dist = std::discrete_distribution<std::size_t>;

    auto G = std::array<normal_dist, 3>{
        normal_dist{5.0, 0.1}, // mean, stddev of G[0]
        normal_dist{8.0, 0.4}, // mean, stddev of G[1]
        normal_dist{2.0, 0.3}  // mean, stddev of G[2]
    };
    auto w = discrete_dist{
        0.1, // weight of G[0]
        0.6, // weight of G[1]
        0.3  // weight of G[2]
    };

    for (int n = 0; n < 100; ++n) {
        // Create one sample of the Gaussian mixture model
        auto index = w(gen);
        auto sample = G[index](gen);
        std::cout << sample << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[Try it out here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cea79ebe7f350207).